# R: two data frame merge

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I want to merge two data frame, but there are some row names repeated.
If the numbers of row name in two data frame are different, I hope the it can show "NA" in the less one column.

My example:

```
test1 <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D"), n1 = c("15", "14", "13", "12", "11", "10"))
test2 <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"), n1 = c("30", "31", "33", "39", "38", "40"))
```

Then I merge by name, I got

> name n1.x n1.y
>
> ```
> A   15   30 
> B   14   31
> B   14   33
> C   13   39
> C   13   38
> C   12   39
> C   12   38
> C   11   39
> C   11   38
> D   10   40
> ```

It will repeating
What I want to is

> name n1.x n1.y
>
> ```
> A   15   30 
> B   14   31
> B   NA   33
> C   13   39
> C   12   38
> C   11   NA
> D   10   40
> ```

What Command should I use?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Very unexected behaviour, can you explain exactly why your desired output contains only two "B" lines and three "C" lines? What are the processing/thinking steps? I guess that what you want is so unusual that you will have to postprocess the output of a regular `merge(test1,test2,by="name")`...

Comment: @jaybee, this situation happen in my experiment, more than 1 observations in same situation. Of course it is unusual, but I have to keep them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
test1$indx <- with(test1, ave(1:nrow(test1), name, FUN=seq_along))
test2$indx <- with(test2, ave(1:nrow(test2), name, FUN=seq_along))
merge(test1, test2, by=c("name","indx"),all=T)[,-2]
 #   name n1.x n1.y
# 1    A   15   30
# 2    B   14   31
# 3    B <NA>   33
# 4    C   13   39
# 5    C   12   38
# 6    C   11 <NA>
# 7    D   10   40
```

Comment: Nice trick, I must remember it. `n1.x` and `n1.y` are factors - is there a way to handle this in your method some other way other than `as.numeric(as.character())`?

Comment: @Roman Lustrik, thanks. `n1` in `test1` and `test2` are both factors.  I don't know why it should be changed to numeric if they both start as factors.  To change it to numeric, `as.numeric(as.character())` would be the route to go.

Comment: Nicely done. No need for `by.x` and `by.y` though. Just `by` once will work as you have the same variable names repeated.

Answer (score 0):

I will post this before `data.table.people` come in with a slick, scalable and quicl solution.

Be warned, that this works for provided data set. You should examine the results of your production code carefully.

What the below code does is sticks together values for a common level. The rest is just bookkeeping.

```
ml <- vector("list", length(unique(test1$name)))
names(ml) <- unique(test1$name)

for (i in unique(test1$name)) {
  o1 <- test1[test1$name %in% i, , drop = FALSE]
  o2 <- test2[test2$name %in% i, , drop = FALSE]
  o.max <- max(c(nrow(o1), nrow(o2)))
  nc <- ifelse(o.max == 1, 2, o.max*2)
  out <- matrix(rep(NA, times = nc), nrow = nc/2)
  out[1:nrow(o1), 1] <- as.numeric(as.character(o1$n1))
  out[1:nrow(o2), 2] <- as.numeric(as.character(o2$n1))

  ml[[i]] <- out
}

count.each <- sapply(ml, nrow)
result <- do.call("rbind", ml)
colnames(result) <- c("n1.x", "n1.y")
data.frame(name = rep(names(ml), count.each), result)

  name n1.x n1.y
1    A   15   30
2    B   14   31
3    B   NA   33
4    C   13   39
5    C   12   38
6    C   11   NA
7    D   10   40
```